# Is it possible to call an entire php file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

What I want to do is when the countdown that I have made reached 0, then it will call my PHP file that contains the code for sending an email. That code does not consist of any UI, the data/message to be emailed is written along with the codes.

I feel that I'm doing it wrong. I'm not also familiar in ajax

my script

```
var end = "<?php echo $endate ?>"; 
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownEnd = new Date(end).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var y = setInterval(function() {

// Get today's date and time
 var noww = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now and the count down date

var distanceEnd = countDownEnd - noww;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
//time ends
var daysEnd = Math.floor(distanceEnd / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hoursEnd = Math.floor((distanceEnd % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 
60 * 60));
var minutesEnd = Math.floor((distanceEnd % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 
60)) - 2;
var secondsEnd = Math.floor((distanceEnd % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Output the result in an element with id="demo"

document.getElementById("daysEnd").innerHTML = daysEnd;
document.getElementById("hoursEnd").innerHTML = hoursEnd;
document.getElementById("minutesEnd").innerHTML = minutesEnd;
document.getElementById("secondsEnd").innerHTML =secondsEnd;

// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (minutesEnd < 0) {
   
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                  url:"../php/reminders.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:""
                });
              }); 

    }
       clearInterval(y);
}

},1000);`
```

my reminders.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'C:\xampp\composer\vendor\autoload.php';
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'admin_man');
$reminders = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE voting_status 
= 
'not yet voted'");

$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reminders)) { 

 try {

  $mail->setFrom('myemail', 'aw');
  $mail->addAddress($row['email']);
  $mail->Subject = 'sample';
  $mail->Body = 'Reminders';
  
  /* SMTP parameters. */
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Username = myemail@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
  $mail->Port = 587;

     /* Enable SMTP debug output. */
    // $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
  
  /* Disable some SSL checks. */
  $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
     'ssl' => array(
     'verify_peer' => false,
     'verify_peer_name' => false,
     'allow_self_signed' => true
     )
  );
  
 }
  catch (Exception $e)
 {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
 }
 catch (\Exception $e)
 {
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }
}
/* Finally send the mail. */
$mail->send();         

?>
```

Comment: Please post your code here as text and not images.

Comment: I already edited it. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Does the email send correctly? What is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: Yes, it does. The only issue is i want to call that file in order to send email automatically.

Comment: Does your countdown work? Is the `ajax` call the only problem you're having?

Comment: Yes, my countdown works fine. Yeah only the ajax call is mu problem.

Comment: I posted an answer, see if it works for you. Also, it is advisable not to post your DB username, password and DB name here, they are irrelevant to the problem anyways.

Comment: Noted sir. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$.post()` function like below. I also put the `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` at the beginning of the code so that nothing starts before the DOM has been loaded.

**Note:** Using `root` as the DB user is not advisable. Create a new user for connecting to the database. Add a password as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var end = "<?php echo $endate ?>";
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownEnd = new Date(end).getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var y = setInterval(function() {
        // Get today's date and time
        var noww = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distanceEnd = countDownEnd - noww;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        //time ends
        var daysEnd = Math.floor(distanceEnd / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hoursEnd = Math.floor((distanceEnd % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutesEnd = Math.floor((distanceEnd % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)) - 2;
        var secondsEnd = Math.floor((distanceEnd % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("daysEnd").innerHTML = daysEnd;
        document.getElementById("hoursEnd").innerHTML = hoursEnd;
        document.getElementById("minutesEnd").innerHTML = minutesEnd;
        document.getElementById("secondsEnd").innerHTML = secondsEnd;

        // If the count down is over, write some text 
        if (minutesEnd < 0) {
          $.post("../php/reminders.php",
            function(data, status) {
              alert("Message sent with status " + status);
            });

          clearInterval(y);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: @stribb You're welcome. Is it working now?

Comment: After trying that code, my countdown is not working. Then, there is an error when i pressed f12. The error says " Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined " in $(documen).ready part

Comment: @stribb you need to add the jQuery script. Add this to the head of your HTML document and under `<title></title>`: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It is finally working, but the problem is the countdown shown in my web page is suddenly stopped in counting down. Then, when i know that my countdown reached 0, it needs to reload the page where my countdown is before it calls my php file to send email.

Comment: @stribb it stops because of calling `clearInterval(y);`. In that case instead of the `alert()` inside the `$.post()` function you can add `location.reload(true);`

Comment: Is there a way that it will only reload once? Because the alert keeps on popping

Comment: Ohw is it because of the setInterval()? Can i terminate the code after executing the code inside the if statement?

Comment: @stribb you are terminating the interval when this `if (minutesEnd < 0)` is true. To reload only once you can use for example [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) or [sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp) to store a value that will be available after reload, for example `localStorage.setItem("relaoded", true)` and have an additional if statement to check `if(localStorage.getItem("relaoded")) {...}` to check whether or not you want to execute the reload, counter or anything else.

Comment: @stribb I suggest you take a look at the two links that I posted in the previous comment and distinguish which of those works best for you.

Comment: It turns out that i misplaced the clearInterval() and i removed the location.reload(true). The problem is solved and it's working perfectly. Thank you for the help!